# Migrating AsyncStorage data when moving from React Native to Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm considering moving from React Native to Expo but to do this have to be able to read the old AsyncStorage data written using the React Native app in the new Expo version.

I was able to build the new Android app using our existing `.keystore` so it correctly replaces the old installed app but the AsyncStorage in the Expo app is empty. I guess it's because it uses different backend? The docs mention this

```
On Android, AsyncStorage will use either RocksDB or SQLite based on what is available.
```

Anyway to workaround this?